# TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I got Visual Studio 2017 community and Team foundation server 2017 installed on my local PC. Every thing went well but I cannot create the first project.

```
--begin Exception entry---
Time: 2017-04-22T21:25:57
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "BuildTask" from Group "Build" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f0024553-93bb-4320-812f-e12aa9e0f70a.
Exception Details: 
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.ProjectComponentCreator.ExecuteInternal(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean validationOnly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.ProjectComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f0024553-93bb-4320-812f-e12aa9e0f70a. (type BuildServerException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildWebService4.CreateTeamProjectComponents(Uri projectUri, IEnumerable`1 permissions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildServer.CreateTeamProjectComponents(Uri projectUri, IEnumerable`1 permissions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.ProjectComponentCreator.ExecuteInternal(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean validationOnly)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f0024553-93bb-4320-812f-e12aa9e0f70a. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: <detail xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ExceptionMessage="The file exists.&#xD;&#xA;" BaseExceptionName="System.IO.IOException" />
Exception Stack Trace:
```

and on event Log:

```
 Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.

Web Request Details
    Url: http://server:8888/tfs/HOANAM/Build/v4.0/BuildService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 15.112.26410.0, Other, SKU:59)
    Headers: not available
    Path: /tfs/HOANAM/Build/v4.0/BuildService.asmx
    Local Request: True
    Host Address: fe80::d173:b6d1:9535:2177%13
    User: SERVER\Administrator [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: The file exists.
 (type IOException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.ProcessTemplate.UpdateCachedProcessParameters(IVssRequestContext requestContext, VersionSpec versionSpec)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.AddProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IList`1 processTemplates)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateBuiltInProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String teamProjectUri, Boolean isUpgrade)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateTeamProject(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String projectUri, IList`1 permissions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.BuildWebService4.CreateTeamProjectComponents(String projectUri, List`1 permissions)
```

I can reach http://server:8888/tfs/HOANAM/Build/v4.0/BuildService.asmx, http://server:8888/tfs/ fine. Also, I tried to delete all files in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

Comment: What's the result if you create a team project through web access? (Go to tfs admin page ([url]/tfs/_admin) > Select a collection > Click Create a new team project)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have more than one instance of TFS installed on the machine, or databases left from another TFS instance. Cleaning these up should help.

Comment: I uninstalled all sql server and tfs instances, clear registry, cache,folders, reboots, but still cannot create new project. So strange.

Comment: At which step you got the error? Is it inside VS or TFS web interface?

Comment: I did that from Visual studio/ team explorer/new team project.  Anyway, I gave up TFS, now I use Bonobo as Git Server, very easy to setup and work well with VS. Thanks for your help.